# Where to put implementation when using Doctest alongside code

Tags: c++, cmake, doctest

I'm using [doctest](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest) for the tests in my C++ project.

I would like to put the test code alongside my implementations, as the library says is possible, but I can't seem to figure out what to do with the doctest implementation code.

I have a `doctest.cpp` file that looks like this:

```cpp
#define DOCTEST_CONFIG_IMPLEMENT_WITH_MAIN
#include "doctest.h"
```

A `main.cpp` that looks like this:

```cpp
#include "thing.h"

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    do_thing();
}
```

`thing.h` is self-explanatory, but `thing.cpp` looks like this:

```cpp
do_thing() {}

TEST_CASE("Test thing") {
    CHECK(1 == 1);
}
```

CMake is used to create two executables, a `Tests` executable and a `Main` executable.

If I don't include `doctest.cpp` in my project sources for `Main`, I get undefined reference errors because it can't find a definition for all the testing stuff in doctest.

However, if I do include it I get errors because there are multiple `main()` functions in one target.

I can't find any info on this in the doctest documentation.

How are you meant to get around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The author of the library gave a good response in this [issue](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest/issues/199):

> DOCTEST_CONFIG_IMPLEMENT_WITH_MAIN implements the test runner and also defines a main() function.
>
> DOCTEST_CONFIG_IMPLEMENT implements ONLY the test runner.
>
> If you define your own main() then you should use DOCTEST_CONFIG_IMPLEMENT - have a look at [the relevant docs](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest/blob/master/doc/markdown/main.md).
>
> You will need the test runner implemented in your main executable (that means doctest.cpp) since you are writing your tests alongside your production code.
>
> You can also define [DOCTEST_CONFIG_DISABLE](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest/blob/master/doc/markdown/configuration.md#doctest_config_disable) when building the main executable so tests are written in the production code but aren't compiled (you will still need doctest.cpp so it all links). This way you won't need to #ifdef the tests.
>
> You could also entirely remove the test executable and use the main executable for running the tests - [docs](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest/blob/master/doc/markdown/main.md).

I went with the first option of writing my own `main()` function.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and one workaround is to add `-DDOCTEST_CONFIG_DISABLE` to the compiler flags when you compile `Main`.

Comment: But this effectively disable the tests.

Comment: @Vinicius. Yes, I think that's the idea when compiling `Main`. One shouldn't include the option `-DDOCTEST_CONFIG_DISABLE ` when compiling `Tests`. The test suit is usually only executed for the latter (`Tests`), while the former (`Main`) compiles the actual program without the tests.