# How to write a makefile which has to generate two executables

Tags: c++, makefile

I am learning how to use make. Recently I wrote a makefile to compile one of my projects, which structure is: **src** (which contains *file.cpp* and *main.cpp*) and **include** (which contains *file.h*) folders and the **makefile**, which is written as follows:

```
TARGET_EXEC := main
CC := g++

BUILD_DIR := .
SRC_DIR := src
OBJ_DIR := obj

SRC := $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -name '*.cpp')
OBJ := $(SRC:%=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
DEPS := $(OBJ:.o=.d)

INC_DIR := $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -type d)
INC_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIR))

CPPFLAGS := $(INC_FLAGS) -MMD -MP

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJ) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.cpp.o: %.cpp
    @ mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -r $(OBJ_DIR) main
    
-include $(DEPS)
```

Now I want to add a new folder (**test**) in which I'll host a *tests.cpp* code with doctest code. In this case I would like to obtain two executables: *main* and *tests* (not only *main* as before), one for the main and one for the testing. I tried everything, but I don't understand how to modify the previous makefile in order to implement the new **test** folder informations.

**EDIT 1**

I tried adding Andreas suggestions and also an *all* command to create both the executables:

```
TARGET_EXEC := main
TEST_EXEC := tests
CC := g++

BUILD_DIR := .
SRC_DIR := src
OBJ_DIR := obj
TEST_DIR := test

SRC := $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -name '*.cpp')
OBJ := $(SRC:%=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
DEPS := $(OBJ:.o=.d)

INC_DIR := $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -type d)
INC_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIR))

CPPFLAGS := $(INC_FLAGS) -MMD -MP

all: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC) $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TEST_EXEC)

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC): $(SRC_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC).o $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJ) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TEST_EXEC): $(TEST_DIR)/$(TEST_EXEC).o $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJ) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.cpp.o: %.cpp
    @ mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean all
clean:
    rm -r $(OBJ_DIR) main
    
-include $(DEPS)
```

Now two executables *main* and *tests* are created, but they do the same things (same of the previous main), so it is wrong. When compile my output is:

```
g++ -Isrc -MMD -MP  -c src/osmanip.cpp -o obj/src/osmanip.cpp.o
g++ -Isrc -MMD -MP  -c src/main.cpp -o obj/src/main.cpp.o
g++ obj/src/osmanip.cpp.o obj/src/main.cpp.o -o main 
g++ obj/src/osmanip.cpp.o obj/src/main.cpp.o -o tests
```

I think that the error may be in:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.cpp.o: %.cpp
    @ mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

What do you think?

**EDIT 2**

Ok, I think that I found a solution:

```
TARGET_EXEC := main
TEST_EXEC := tests
CC := g++

BUILD_DIR := .
SRC_DIR := src
OBJ_DIR := obj
TEST_DIR := test

SRC := $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -name '*.cpp')
TEST := $(shell find $(TEST_DIR) -name '*.cpp')
OBJ := $(SRC:%=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
TEST_OBJ := $(TEST:%=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
DEPS := $(OBJ:.o=.d)

INC_DIR := $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -type d)
INC_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIR))

CPPFLAGS := $(INC_FLAGS) -MMD -MP

.PHONY: clean all

all: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC) $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TEST_EXEC)

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJ) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TEST_EXEC): $(TEST_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(TEST_OBJ) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.cpp.o: %.cpp
    @ mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -r $(OBJ_DIR) main tests
    
-include $(DEPS)
```

With this makefile the compilation is good (I think), since the **obj/src** and **obj/test** folder are created. *main* executable is compiled correctly and works. Also *tests* executable is compiled (correclty I think), but I get another error, not related to makefile:

```
g++ -Isrc -MMD -MP  -c src/osmanip.cpp -o obj/src/osmanip.cpp.o
g++ -Isrc -MMD -MP  -c src/main.cpp -o obj/src/main.cpp.o
g++ obj/src/osmanip.cpp.o obj/src/main.cpp.o -o main 
g++ -Isrc -MMD -MP  -c test/tests.cpp -o obj/test/tests.cpp.o
g++ obj/test/tests.cpp.o -o tests 
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:29: tests] Error 1
```

I think this is due to the fact that my *test/tests.cpp* file is

```
#define DOCTEST_CONFIG_IMPLEMENT
#include "doctest/doctest.h"
#include <string>
```

I didn't give it any command for the moment. I implemented doctest without main and in fact it tells me that main function is missing (because it is implemented into the *src/main.cpp* file). I tried looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55216866/where-to-put-implementation-when-using-doctest-alongside-code) answer, but I didn't solve this problem.

Do you know how to correctly compile the doctest *test.cpp* file? Thanks.

**EDIT 3**

Thanks to Jarod42 answer I solved also this very last issue related to doctest. Now all seems working perfectly.

Many thanks to sll you guys! It is my first post on Stack Overflow and I alrealy love this site.

Comment: Did you intend to build `src/obj/file.o` or `obj/file.o`? That is, do you want `obj/` to be in `src/` or in the parent directory of `src/`?

Comment: Your problem for Edit 1 is using $(OBJ) in the new recipes instead of automatic variable $^. Also, OBJ still contains main.o. That was like the one thing that mattered in my answer ;-)

Comment: Hi @Andreas I added another Edit in which I probably solved the issue. But another problem appears and is related to the correct test.cpp (with doctest) compilation, in case in which test.cpp doesn't have a main function. Do you know how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: I'd add that your struggle with this issue is normal. It can be very difficult (but still quite common) to manage projects with `make` as their number of targets grow. That's why tools such as `cmake` and `autoconf` exist to help generate makefiles for more complex projects. Food for thought if your project gets more complex.

Comment: You probably want that `#define` `DOCTEST_CONFIG_IMPLEMENT_WITH_MAIN`.

Comment: Thanks @SamBob for the hint! I plan to start studying also cmake in future, but since I deal with makefile only for my job (I deal with a data analysis software for the ATLAS particle physics experimet) I am focusing on it at the moment.

Comment: In retrospect I don't think I fully understand what it is you are doing, like where the main() is and how the tests are supposed to work. All is well that ends well? Lessons for both of us I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have tried humble beginnings? Here is where I would start and build on, key being to separate the main.o from OBJ so that tests can have its main from tests.o:

```
# Adding include directories (weird way of doing it but ok)
CPPFLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(shell find src -type d))

# object files
OBJ := src/file1.o src/file2.o

# main
main: src/main.o $(OBJ)

# the test program
tests: test/tests.o $(OBJ)
```

(Notice this relies on built-in recipes, should work out-of-the-box.)

From there you can re-introduce the other concepts step by step:

- Out-of-tree build.

  - Overrated (at least for GNU Make for which it's all manual).
- Glob source files.

  - If you know what files you have, best not glob.
- Dependency file generation and inclusion.
- Keep folders and such in variables.

Comment: Hi Andreas, thanks for your comment. I edited my question with your information. Unfortunately it doesn't work again.